# How to hide History section ("Member for") in Drupal user profile page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using drupal7. I have listed user profiles. In user profile detail page contains history. It shows like **'Member for 22 hours 15 min '**

I want to hide the history section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow to Configuration -> People -> Account settings -> Manage Display (`admin/config/people/accounts/display`) and set History's format to "hidden".

Answer (score 1):

[tulvit provides definitely the easiest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13620849/1127583) but if you need to do this via code than you can use [hook_user_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_view_alter/7).

In a custom module add:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_view_alter().
 */
function YOURCUSTOMMODULE_user_view_alter(&$build) {
  unset($build['summary']);
}
```

The variable $build['summary'] holds all the information for rendering the History section of the user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope these links will be useful to u :) [How can I remove History from profile](http://drupal.org/node/138127) and [Customizing the user profile layout](http://drupal.org/node/35728)

Points from the above links...
1. copy the following code

```
<?php
// $Id: user-profile-category.tpl.php,v 1.2 2007/08/07 08:39:36 goba Exp $

/**
 * @file user-profile-category.tpl.php
 * Default theme implementation to present profile categories (groups of
 * profile items).
 *
 * Categories are defined when configuring user profile fields for the site.
 * It can also be defined by modules. All profile items for a category will be
 * output through the $profile_items variable.
 *
 * @see user-profile-item.tpl.php
 *      where each profile item is rendered. It is implemented as a definition
 *      list by default.
 * @see user-profile.tpl.php
 *      where all items and categories are collected and printed out.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $title: Category title for the group of items.
 * - $profile_items: All the items for the group rendered through
 *   user-profile-item.tpl.php.
 * - $attributes: HTML attributes. Usually renders classes.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_user_profile_category()
 */
?>
<?php if ($title && $title != t(History)) : ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($title != t(History)) : ?>
<dl<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print $profile_items; ?>
</dl>
<?php endif; ?>
```

2. Save the above code in a file named "`user-profile-category.tpl.php`" (Pls do not use any other names since we have over ride the Drupal's core tpl file) and Save the mentioned file into the root folder of the theme whichever your using...
3. Confirm that you are using the same theme (as we override the tpl file for the particular theme)
4. Clear the cache and See the result :)

Comment: please summarize steps/howto from above links in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings » Manage Display